# Laravel 5 unique (database) validation with different date format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using laravel 5.5 with MySQL database.

Here is my current code:

```
private function setValidationRule(Request $request,$actionCode) {
    $rules = [];
    $rules['odaydate'] = 'required|unique:empofday|date_format:"d-m-Y"';
    return $rules;
}

public function postCreate(Request $request) {
    //Previous code...

    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),
        $this->setValidationRule($request,$actionCode),
        $this->setCustomValidationRuleMsg($request,$actionCode)
    );
    $validator->setAttributeNames($this->setValidationAttributeNames());
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $view = $viewPri->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    } else {
        $view = $viewSec;
    }
    return $view;
}
```

The posting data from client is DD-MM-YYYY = '15-10-2018'.

Then i want to validate the date uniqueness with the rule :
`$rules['odaydate'] = 'required|unique:empofday|date_format:"d-m-Y"';`

Yes the validation is true (success) but the laravel generated sql was wrong to get the uniqueness :
`select count(*) as aggregate from empofday where odaydate = '15-10-2018'`
so the resulting sql would be 0 instead of 1.

But if i try manual sql with the following code :
`select count(*) as aggregate from empofday where odaydate = '2018-10-01'`
resulting value 1.

So, my question is how to set date format for laravel validating uniqueness on database to **use d-m-Y format instead of Y-m-d**?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Ow yeah forgot to tell, i'm using MySQL. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using simple text box for date input, I recommend to change that to some date picker plugin, the plugins do have functionality to have a date format that is displayed different than what is sent back to the database.

After that you can remove the date format validation, because it will be managed by the plugin, and unique will run because the format sent by the plugin can be set to be in MySQL format (YYYY-MM-DD)

For jQuery UI Date picker
    http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, at the 3rd point, should i query the database manually or still using laravel validation? If still using laravel validation, how to convert the $request date value before validation happen?

Comment: I thought you were getting error at query running, but now i understand that you are getting error at validation, let me check what can be done.

Comment: You are using unique:empofday, try unique:empofday,odaydate

Comment: No the validation for unique run successfully. But the result always 0 which mean the unique cannot found the duplicate value. (I already explain the sql generated by laravel in my question above)

Comment: Are you using simple text box for date input, if yes i recommend to change that to some date picker plugin, the plugins do have functionality to have a date format that is displayed different than what is sent back to the database.

Comment: after that you can remove the date format validation, because it will be managed by the plugin, and uinque will run because the format sent by the plugin can be set to be in mysql format.

Comment: This is it from my side, if you find the post helpful you can up vote it, that it was useful and if it has solved your problem you can accept it. I am going to edit it to be as the last comments

Comment: Hmm.. I'm already using datepicker plugin, but inside my application, all the value always keep the date format DD-MM-YYYY. My goal was to find the ways how to change laravel unique validation date format on validation. As a workaround i will try your suggestion to post different format to server than what it shown to user. Thanks for the help.